# To nest conditionals inside your Main, or to not nest conditionals

Tags: structure, methodology

## Issue

Attempting to identify which is the best practice for executing sequential methods. Either, nesting conditionals one after another, or nesting conditionals one inside another, within a main function. In addition, if you could supply "why" one method would be better than the other besides what's most acceptable, I'd sincerely appreciate it. Here are my examples:

> Nesting one after another

```cpp
int main()
{
    // conditional 1
    if (!method_one())
    {
       ... do something
    } 
    else 
    {
       ... prompt error for method 1!
    }

    // conditional 2
    if (!method_two())
    {
       ... do something
    } 
    else 
    {
       ... prompt error for method 2!
    }

    // conditional 3
    if (!method_three())
    {
       ... do something
    } 
    else 
    {
       ... prompt error for method 3!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Nesting one inside another

```cpp
int main()
{
    // conditional 1
    if (!method_one())
    {
       if (!method_two())
       {
          if (!method_three())
          {
              ... next steps in sequence
          } 
          else 
          {
             ... prompt error for method 3!
          }
          ... prompt error for method 2!
       }
       ... prompt error for method 1!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Observations

I've seen both used, however, not sure which is better practice and/or more commonly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The two options aren't actually entirely logically identical - in the "Nesting one after another", for example, `method_two()` will run even if `method_one()` fails; if `method_two()` has any side effects this may be undesirable. Furthermore, if both `method_one()` and `method_two()` are destined to fail, "Nesting one after another" will print two error prompts, whereas 'Nesting one inside another" will only error prompt on `method_one()`.

You could close the difference by appending a `goto End` at the end of each `else` in "Nesting one after another", so it skips over the remaining checks, but the use of `goto` would probably get you slapped. Alternatively, you could `return` at the end of each else, perhaps with an error code, and let whoever is calling your `main` function deal with understanding what went wrong.

With that in mind, "Nesting one after another" is probably easier to read and understand, since there's less indentation/the code is kept flat, and what happens on failure is immediately next to the check. (That 2nd point can be addressed by reordering the error prompt for `method_one()` to before the check for `method_two()` for "Nesting one inside another")